# How can I avoid timeout in immediate window?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have a regular, **in-memory** `List<T>` containing approximatley 10k items. When I'm trying to query this list in the visual studio immediate window I get an error:

```
MyList.Where(m => m.Name.StartsWith("x"))
{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator<T>}
    Error: Evaluation timed out
```

I checked the source for [`System.Linq.WhereListIterator<T>`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,979cb1fc22e29394) and it does not appear to throw any exceptions, so I'm guessing it is the immediate window that decides when to time out the query. Is there any way to configure when to time out or avoid this in another way?

Comment: 3 years, 6 upvotes, 264 view, and nobody can answer this?

Answer (score 5):

Just evaluate this expression using `ToArray()` or `ToList()` like this `MyList.Where(m => m.Name.StartsWith("x")).ToList()`.

Comment: I get stack overflows or the debugger just hangs. Visual Studio Version 17.8.0 Preview 2.0. Dotnet 8.0.0-rc.1